# ros code: expired license svn?

Tags: ros, svn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to download the source code of a few packages to build with rosinstall on armhf, but when i try to register on code.ros.org it says the license is expired ? So how or where can I download the source code ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/90941/ros-code:-expired-license-svn-?/) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2013-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

code.ros.org is inactive. Most code has been ported to other locations, e.g. github.

Check the package website in the ROS wiki. That should contain a link to the currently maintained code repository.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2